# What substitution do I use for simple regions integration?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

Let $G=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : 4\leq x^2-y^2\leq 5,x\geq 6y,y\geq 0\}$. Calculate
$$
\iint _G 4(x^2-y^2)\frac{x-y}{x}\,dA
$$

I'm pretty sure I could solve it further but can't seem to get a right substitution.

Comment: please write what you have tried :). this way we can provide you with insights that align with your attempt

Comment: It looks like the problem writer went out of their way to make the substitution seem obvious. Looking at your bounds and the integrand, could you at least guess what one of your variables has to be?

Comment: $x^2 -y^2 $ for one i think

Comment: Perfect. Your other hint is separate the fraction.

Comment: so $y/x$ for the second one?

Comment: and then $0<=(y/x)<=1/6$ ?

Comment: That's what I would guess! Go for it.